# How can I remedy lingering foundation leaks after repairs?

Tags: basement, foundation, waterproofing, flooding

A couple of years ago, I bought an older house (1930s) that had been flipped by the seller. They had finished the basement (~850 sqft) by adding drywall and carpet. They also plugged up the sump pump.

Come winter, we discovered that they did not do any waterproofing, and groundwater would leak in through the foundation during heavy rains. It's never a substantial amount of water – large puddles – but enough to cause mold problems over time. The leaking started in one room. We removed the carpet, removed the bottom of the drywall, cleaned any mold, added Dryloc waterproofing concrete to the foundation in all leaky areas, leveled the concrete floor, and replaced the drywall.

Then, it would leak in another room. So we would do the same process. We've overhauled 3/5 rooms at this point and it's now leaking in a 4th room. I am at a loss as to how to fix this more permanently, or creatively work around it, without breaking the bank. I would still like to utilize this area as living space (guest room, office), but I don't want to worry about furniture being ruined or drywall collecting mold.

We have downspouts facing away from the house. Someone also installed a concrete perimeter around the house at some point many years ago.

Could anyone give me any ideas? Looking to spend under $7k ideally.

Should I replace the drywall with something else? Add interlocking raised floor panels?

Comment: Given the many potential aggravating factors and the work you've already done, this calls for a local expert. We'd be throwing darts at the problem just as you have been. That said, you mentioned "winter". Groundwater doesn't rise in winter where I am, so I assume you mean "the rainy season". If that's the case, have you looked at rain gutters and yard grade improvements?

Comment: Plugging up the sump pump probably was a mistake.  Water is not being taken away anymore so is finding different ways to make your life misable.

Comment: Indeed, what does "plugged" mean? Can you return the sump system to service? That sounds like it may be an easy win.

Comment: Prior to having read any of the comments, "They also plugged up the sump pump" screamed "THIS IS THE PROBLEM!!!" at me. I'd recommend talking with someone local to get the sump working again so that any water that wants to come in ends up in the sump pit, then gets pumped out instead of ending up running across the concrete floor ruining your carpet & drywall.

Comment: "Plugged" up the sump pump/well.  Sounds like something a flipper would do.  That way they wouldn't have to answer any questions about "why is there a sump pump in the basement?  Do you have a water problem?".

Comment: Sorry, I know "plugged" was strange terminology to use. They filled the sump pit hole with concrete. HOWEVER, zero water has reached anywhere close to that area. It's in the laundry room, the only unfinished room, the only room that hasn't leaked, and that may have been the only waterproofing they did on the foundation. So I really don't think it would offer any help even if it was still there.

Comment: @Kelsey it doesn't matter if zero water has reached the sump area. A sump is pretty much defined as the lowest point—not necessarily the lowest point of your interior—so if the sump is gone the water has nowhere else to go. So it comes out in other places.  Think of your house as a bathtub with tiny perforations along the bottom edge of the sides.  If you put the tub in a pond, water will come up through the drain hole.  If you can remove it fast enough, the tub will more or less remain dry.  If you plug the hole, water will start coming in through the perforations.

Comment: That's a very helpful visual – I was not aware of that. Thank you!